# joinPolys function in PBSmapping gives NULL output

Tags: r

I am using the function joinPolys in the R package PBSmapping to find intersections between polygons. However it is giving a NULL output with my data, even though I am pretty sure the intersection is non-empty.

I've created an example from https://code.google.com/p/pbs-mapping/issues/detail?id=31. In the link, the code is designed to show a case where the code does work (but doesn't work for me). The example is as follows:

Code does not work:

```
require(PBSmapping)

polyA <- data.frame(PID=rep(1,4),POS=1:4,X=c(0,1,1,0),Y=c(0,0,1,1))
polyB <- data.frame(PID=rep(1,4),POS=1:4,X=c(.5,1.5,1.5,.5),Y=c(.5,.5,1.5,1.5))

# Plot polygons
plotPolys(polyA, xlim=c(0,3), ylim=c(0,3))
addPolys(polyB, border=2)

# returns NULL
print(joinPolys(polyA, polyB))
```

However, in other cases, the code does work:

```
require(PBSmapping)

N <- 4

X = cos(seq(0, 2*pi, length = N))
Y = sin(seq(0, 2*pi, length = N))

require(PBSmapping)
polysA1 = data.frame(PID = rep(1, N), POS = 1:N, 
  X = 5*X, Y = 5*Y)
polysB1 = data.frame(PID = rep(1, N), POS = 1:N, 
  X = 5*X + 5, Y = 5*Y)
plotMap(NULL, xlim = c(-10, 10), ylim = c(-10, 10))
addPolys(polysA1, col = 'blue', lty = 12, density = 0, pch = 16)
addPolys(polysB1, col = 'red', lty = 12, density = 0, pch = 16)
addPolys(joinPolys(polysA1, polysB1), col = 2)

print(head(joinPolys(polysA1, polysB1)))
```

I am using R version 3.1.3, and Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS.

Thanks in advance! I'm new to stackoverflow, so please let me know if there is anything else I can provide.

Cheers

Comment: I don't get a `NULL` intersection. It appears to be correct for me. I'm using PBSmapping 2.66.53

Comment: hmm thats weird. I was using PBSmapping 2.68.68, but just tried it with 2.66.53 and it gave NULL for me. I'll try it with the other versions.

Comment: gives NULL for all versions 2.65.40, 2.66.53, 2.67.60, 2.68.68. @nicola, which version of R are you using?

Comment: 3.1.2 on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: I got it to work (most of the time) with R 2.15.0, and PBSmapping 2.64.40.